# Bingo card generator

Tags: code-golf, game

A Bingo card is five columns of five squares each, with the middle square designated "FREE".  Numbers cannot duplicate.

The five columns are populated with the following range of numbers:

- B:1-15
- I:16-30
- N:31-45
- G:46-60
- O:61-75

In as few characters as possible, output a string that can be interpreted as a randomized Bingo card.
For example:

> 1,2,3,4,5,16,17,18,19,20,31,32,33,34,35,46,47,48,49,50,61,62,63,64,65

This example is not randomized so that I can show that column 1 is populated with 1,2,3,4,5.  Also note that the free space has not been given any special treatment because the front-end that interprets this string will skip it.

Another example would be:

> 1,16,31,46,61,2,17,32,47,62...

In this example, the output is by row instead of by column.

A third example might be:

> 01020304051617181920313233343546474849506162636465

This is the same output as the 1st example except in fixed length.

Comment: Yes!  That's it!  My idea is to come up with a list of 75 or more words and populate the card with SELECT * FROM List ORDER BY NEWID()

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 38 bytes

```r
cat(apply(matrix(1:75,,5),2,sample,5))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCOxoCCnUiM3saQos0LD0MrcVEfHVFPHSKc4MbcgJxXI1vz/HwA)

(another 7 years [later](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/bingo-card-generator/257259#comment237021_97529)...  )

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 86

```
for($o=[];25>$i=count($o);){$n=rand(1,15)+($i-$i%5)*3;$o[$n]=$n;}echo implode(",",$o);
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, nice first answer c:

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed a bit too late that this question is 5 years old... xD Not sure if it matters though

Comment: `join` is an alias for `ìmplode` and you can put the assigment in the after loop. This will shorten your idea to `for($o=[];25>$i=count($o);$o[$n]=$n)$n=rand(1,15)+($i-$i%5)*3;echo join(",",$o);`

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>63</s> <s>51</s> <s>50</s> <s>49</s> 45 bytes

Thanks to Billywob for ongoing suggestions and encouraging my competitive streak.

```
cat(sapply(split(n<-1:75,cut(n,5)),sample,5))
```

> 5 14 15 3 1 20 30 28 18 27 32 45 42 43 41 49 54 50 56 47 68 66 64 73 71

Comment: The vectorized approach I tried is a bit shorter.`cat(sapply(list(15,16:30,31:45,46:60,61:75),sample,5))` Edit: never mind the printing, added `cat` instead

Comment: @Billywob Thanks, that's a great answer! I have since found one that's even shorter. (Not vectorized, unfortunately.)

Comment: Turns you can do even better: `cat(sapply(split(1:75,ceiling(1:75/15)),sample,5))`. Works by splitting the vector `1:75` into a list where each element is a vector of length `15` instead of using `list()` to pass objects to `sapply`.

Comment: Very nice! I had your solution posted for a few seconds, but then I figured out how to outgolf you by a single byte.

Comment: Hah! Even better. But I don't think you need the `labels = FALSE` option for `cut`. Because all that matters is that there are `5` repeating factors passed to the split function, regardless of names.

Comment: Well I'll be damned. Thanks! Together we have made the shortest code for the question (so far), a rare feat! Although, given that the question is about 5 years old, perhaps I shouldn't be surprised.

Answer (score 1):

### Windows PowerShell, 51 <s>54</s>

I'm not sure whether I understood your task correctly, though.

```
(0..4|%{($x=15*$_+1)..($x+14)|random -c 5})-join','
```

Sample outputs:

```
5,9,1,7,13,26,18,23,17,22,37,33,34,41,44,50,53,59,60,58,73,72,64,69,66
14,10,13,5,1,24,29,26,17,30,34,33,43,41,38,59,50,60,49,56,71,61,72,70,68
3,11,4,5,13,27,16,25,26,22,43,34,42,32,38,51,52,49,58,54,61,70,73,71,62
1,9,13,12,4,23,25,20,26,22,40,33,35,44,37,55,47,52,59,53,74,70,75,64,69
8,6,7,1,9,16,21,23,18,17,35,41,37,38,34,60,50,57,51,59,66,75,73,74,71
11,6,13,4,1,29,27,24,22,18,40,35,41,32,43,51,54,57,58,53,74,71,69,66,64
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby 1.9, 48 characters

```
$><<(0..4).map{|i|[*1..75][15*i,15].sample 5}*?,
```

Answer (score 1):

**PHP 106**

```
<?$z=1;for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){for($j=0;$j<rand(1,5);$j++){$o[]=rand($z,$z+15);}$z+=15;}echo implode(",", $o);
```

I'm not sure I understood correctly the problem... Can you provide a more detailed explanation?

Comment: The output is incorrect. You always need to output all 25 squares :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
75ɾ15ẇƛÞ℅5Ẏ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI3Ncm+MTXhuofGm8Oe4oSFNeG6jiIsIiIsIiJd)

```
75ɾ         # range(1, 75)
   15ẇ      # Cut into chunks of 15
      ƛ     # Over each
       Þ℅   # Shuffle
         5Ẏ # Get the first five items
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure - 52 chars

```
(map #(take 5(shuffle %))(partition 15(range 1 76)))
```

Example output (note that it provides the separate rows as sub-lists):

```
((4 1 12 10 2) (25 23 21 16 27) (39 33 45 44 43) (48 53 59 54 47) (73 71 61 64 63))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 84 bytes

```python
from random import*
print sum([sample(range(1+i*15,16+i*15),5)for i in range(5)],[])
```

If the output as list if lists is okay there is a **75 bytes** solution:

```python
from random import*
print[sample(range(1+i*15,16+i*15),5)for i in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
75õ òF Ëá5 ö
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=NzX1IPJGIMvhNSD2&input=LVE) (or [formatted as a Bingo card](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=NzX1IPJGIMvhNSD2&footer=1WkiQklOR08irCD5MiBtuLc))