# Code Golf Bingo!

Tags: code-golf

You are given a [Bingo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingo_%28U.S.%29) board and a list of calls.  You must print BINGO! as soon as your board wins the game.

Bingo boards look like this:

[image]

They will be specified like this:

```
14 29 38 52 74
4 18 33 46 62
7 16 * 60 71
9 27 44 51 67
12 23 35 47 73
```

Immediately following the board will be calls, like this:

```
B7
I29
G60
G51
O71
I23
I16
N38
```

You must echo the calls out to standard output until just after the call that makes you win (get a row, column, or 5-long diagonal all filled), then print `BINGO!`.

For the above example, print:

```
B7
I29
G60
G51
O71
I23
I16
BINGO!
```

**Rules**

Standard code-golf rules, shortest code wins.

**Details**

There will always be enough calls to guarantee you a Bingo.  There will be no duplicate numbers on the board, and no duplicate calls.  Boards will always have correctly matched numbers and letters (the `B` column contains only 1-15, the `I` column contains only 16-30, and so on), as will calls.  The one and only free space will always be in the middle, marked with `*` instead of a number.  Consuming and discarding calls from standard input after the winning call is allowed, but not required.

[Make your own test cases!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/bingo-card-generator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Perl, <strike>122</strike> 120 char

```
$b=join'. .
',map~~<>,0..4;while(<>){/(\d+)/;$b=~s/\b$1\b/*/;print;
$b=~/(\*\s(\S+\s){$_}){4}\*/&&die"BINGO!
"for 0..7}
```

Build the card in `$b` with two additional junky columns.
Replace the numbers that are called on the card with `*` and print the called number.
Then the last regular expression will evaluate to true when there are 5 regularly spaced `*`s on the board.

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby 1.9 (194, 130)

This probably isn't the most sensible way to check for empty columns, but it was the first thing I thought to try!  In particular, that `#transpose` costs a lot.

Either a blank line between the board and the numbers or fixed width fields when declaring the board would save a lot of characters.  I couldn't think of a really nice way to read exactly 5 lines.

```ruby
b=(R=0..4).map{gets}.join.scan /\d+|\*/
loop{gets
puts$_
~/\d+/
(e=b.index$&)&&b[e]=?*
R.map{|y|$><<:BINGO!&&exit if R.map{|x|[b[5*x+y],b[5*y+x],b[y<1?x*6:4*x+4]]}.transpose.any?{|a|a==[?*]*5}}}
```

**EDIT:** 130 character solution using the regular expression technique from mob's perl answer:

```
b=(0..4).map{gets}*'~ ~ '
loop{gets
puts$_
~/\d+/
b[/\b#$&\b/]=?*
7.times{|i|$><<:BINGO!&&exit if b=~/(\*\s(\S+\s){#{i}}){4}\*/m}}
```

Answer (score 4):

### C# – 536

(OK, this is probably not the most suitable language for that, but anyway…)

```cs
using System;using System.Collections.Generic;using System.Linq;class C{static void Main(){var s=Enumerable.Range(1,12).Select(_=>new HashSet<string>()).ToList();var b=Enumerable.Range(1,5).Select(_=>Console.ReadLine().Split(' ')).ToList();int i;for(i=0;i<5;++i){for(int j=0;j<5;++j){s[i].Add(b[i][j]);s[i+5].Add(b[j][i]);}s[10].Add(b[i][i]);s[11].Add(b[4-i][i]);}while(i>0){var l=Console.ReadLine();Console.WriteLine(l);l=l.Substring(1);foreach(var x in s){x.Remove("*");x.Remove(l);if(x.Count==0){Console.WriteLine("BINGO!");i=0;}}}}}
```

Formatted and commented:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class C
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // all possible winnable five-item sets – any one of them need to be emptied to win
        var s = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(_ => new HashSet<string>()).ToList();
        // read the board from input to a list of arrays of numbers
        var b = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(_ => Console.ReadLine().Split(' ')).ToList();
        int i;
        // split the board into the winnable sets
        for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            {
                // sets 0–4 represent rows
                s[i].Add(b[i][j]);
                // sets 5–9 represent columns
                s[i + 5].Add(b[j][i]);
            }
            // set 10 represent one diagonal
            s[10].Add(b[i][i]);
            // set 11 represent the other diagonal
            s[11].Add(b[4 - i][i]);
        }
        while (i > 0)
        {
            // read and echo another input
            var l = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(l);
            // ignore the initial letter – we are guaranteed it is correct, anyway
            l = l.Substring(1);
            // remove the number from all sets
            foreach (var x in s)
            {
                x.Remove(l);
                // also remove the center * (inside the loop just to shave off a few characters)
                x.Remove("*");
                // if any set became empty, we won!
                if (x.Count == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("BINGO!");
                    // ensure the loop will stop (might not be necessary per the rules, but anyway)
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

*Given the long, long, long overdue announcement of Rebol's [impending release as open source software](http://www.rebol.com/article/0512.html), I returned to my pet dialect to solve [this Bingo problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8501/code-golf-bingo/).  I may soon be able to distribute Rebmu as its own, teensy GPL package.  :)*

---

### [Rebmu](http://hostilefork.com/rebmu/) 88 characters

In the compact notation:

```
rtZ5[GisGpcRaZisGaAPgPCaSB6zAPv'*]l5[AgL5[apGfAsk+A5]]hd+Gu[raGin-NTrM'*fisGv5]p"BINGO!"
```

The dialect uses a trick I call *mushing* which is explained on the [Rebmu page](http://hostilefork.com/rebmu/).  It's "legit" in the sense that it doesn't cheat the parser; this is valid Rebol...and can actually can be freely intermingled with ordinary code as well as (ahem) "long-form" Rebmu...which BTW would be 141 characters:

`[rt z 5 [g: is g pc r a z is g a ap g pc a sb 6 z ap v '*] l 5 [a: g l 5 [ap g f a sk+ a 5]] hd+ g u [ra g in- nt r m '* fis g v 5] p "BINGO!"]`

*(Given that I claim the compression is a trick that one can do without the help of automation or compilation, I actually develop the code in the mushed form.  It's not difficult.)*

It's actually quite simple, nothing special--I'm sure other Rebol programmers could shave things off.  Some  [commented source is on GitHub](https://github.com/hostilefork/rebmu/blob/master/examples/bingo.rebmu), but the main trick I use is to build all the possible solutions in a long series ("list", "array", what-have-you).  I  build the diagonal solutions during the input loop, as it takes five insertions at the head and five appends at the tail to make them...and there's already a five-iteration loop in progress.

The whole thing easily maps to Rebol code, and I haven't yet thrown any "matrix libraries" into Rebmu with transposition or other gimmicks that seem to come up often.  Someday I will do that but for now I'm just trying to work relatively close to the medium of Rebol itself.  Cryptic-looking things like:

```
 [g: is g pc r a z is g a ap g pc a sb 6 z ap v '*]
```

...are rather simple:

```
 [
     ; assign the series pointer "g" to the result of inserting 
     ; the z'th element picked out of reading in some series
     ; from input that was stored in "a"...this pokes an element
     ; for the forward diagonal near the front of g
     g: insert g (pick (readin-mu a) z)

     ; insert the read-in series "a" from above into "g" as well,
     ; but *after* the forward diagonal elements we've added...
     insert g a

     ; for the reverse diagonal, subtract z from 6 and pick that
     ; (one-based) element out of the input that was stored in "a"
     ; so an element for the reverse diagonal is at the tail
     append g (pick a (subtract 6 z))

     ; so long as we are counting to 5 anyway, go ahead and add an
     ; asterisk to a series we will use called "v" to search for
     ; a fulfilled solution later
     append v '*
 ]
```

*Note: Parentheses added above for clarity.  But Rebol programmers (like English speakers) generally eschew the application of extra structural callouts for indicating the grammar in communication...rather save them for other applications...*

Just as an added bonus to show how interesting this actually is, I'll throw in some mix of normal code to sum the board.  The programming styles are actually...compatible:

```
rtZ5[GisGpcRaZisGaAPgPCaSB6zAPv'*]
temp-series: g
sum: 0
loop 5 * 5 [
    square: first temp-series
    if integer! == type? square [
        sum: sum + square
    ]
    temp-series: next temp-series
]
print ["Hey grandma, the board sum is" sum]
l5[AgL5[apGfAsk+A5]]hd+Gu[raGin-NTrM'*fisGv5]p"BINGO!"
```

That's valid Rebmu as well, and it will give you a nice board sum before playing Bingo with you.  In the example given, it says `Hey grandma, the board sum is 912`.  Which is probably right.  But you get the point.  :)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 250

Disclosure: I assumed that the input was given in lists which are far more natural to use for Mathematica. So,with `b` representing the board and `c` representing the calls,

```
b//Grid
c//Column
```

[image: input]

If the input were to be in strings, the code would grow by about 30 characters.  (I'll later include that variation.)

**Code**

```
y = ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, {5, 5}], {3, 3} -> 1]; d = Diagonal;
t := Tr[BitAnd @@@ Join[y, Transpose@y, {d@y}, {d[Reverse /@ y]}]] > 0;
r@i_ :=(y = ReplacePart[y, Position[x, ToExpression@StringDrop[i, 1]][[1]] -> 1]; 
Print@If[t, Column[{i, "BINGO!"}], i])
n = 1; While[! t, r@c[[n]]; n++]
```

> B7
>
> I29
>
> G60
>
> G51
>
> O71
>
> I23
>
> I16
>
> BINGO!

Answer (score 2):

## Python 249

```
R=raw_input;F=B=[[[x,0][x=='*']for x in row]for row in[R().split()for i in'11111']];A=any
while all([all(map(A,B)),all(map(A,zip(*B))),A(F[::6]),A(F[4:24:4])]):c=R();print c;C=c[1:];B=[[[x,0][x==C]for x in row]for row in B];F=sum(B,[])
print'BINGO!'
```

#### Usage:

```
$ ./bingo.py < bingo.txt
B7
I29
G60
G51
O71
I23
I16
BINGO!
```

Comment: You could replace `row` by a one-char name. Untested: try `i in'*'*5]` and replace `[x=='*']` with `[x==i]`.

Answer (score 2):

### APL (82)

```
{(D≡(⍵∨⌽⍵)∧D←=/¨⍳⍴⍵)∨∨/(∧⌿⍵)∨∧/⍵:'BINGO!'⋄∇⍵∨B=⍎1↓⎕←⍞}0=B←↑{⍎(K,K)[⍞⍳⍨K←11↑⎕D]}¨⍳5
```

- `{`...`}¨⍳5`: do 5 times:
- `⍎(K,K)[⍞⍳⍨K←11↑⎕D]`: read a line (`⍞`) and map all characters that aren't digits or space to `0`, then evaluate the line.
- `B←↑`: turn it into a matrix (5x5 if the input was correct), and store in B.
- `{`...`}0=B`: the starting board has a 1 in the free space (0) and 0 in the other spaces.
- `(D≡(⍵∨⌽⍵)∧D←=/¨⍳⍴⍵)∨∨/(∧⌿⍵)∨∧/⍵`: if a line, a column, or a diagonal is filled:
- `'BINGO!'`: then output `BINGO`
- `∇⍵∨B=⍎1↓⎕←⍞`: otherwise, read a line (`⍞`), echo it (`⎕←`), drop the first character (`1↓`), evaluate it to get a number (`⍎`), see where it occurs on the board (`B=`), mark it (`⍵∨`), and try again (`∇`).

Answer (score 0):

## K, 114

Given the board `b` and the calls `c`

```
b{-1@y;a:(5*!5)_@[,/x;&(,/x)~\:1_y;:;"*"];$[max{max@min'"*"=,/'x}@/:(a;a ./:/:+:'(r;)'(r;|:r:!5));'"BINGO!";];a}/c
```

.

```
k)b
"14" "29" "38" "52" "74"
,"4" "18" "33" "46" "62"
,"7" "16" ,"*" "60" "71"
,"9" "27" "44" "51" "67"
"12" "23" "35" "47" "73"
k)c
"B7"
"I29"
"G60"
"G51"
"O71"
"I23"
"I16"
"N38"
k)b{-1@y;a:(5*!5)_@[,/x;&(,/x)~\:1_y;:;"*"];$[max{max@min'"*"=,/'x}@/:(a;a ./:/:+:'(r;)'(r;|:r:!5));'"BINGO!";];a}/c
B7
I29
G60
G51
O71
I23
I16
'BINGO
```