# Create a bingo card generator

Tags: code-golf, number, grid, random, game

## Bingo

Bingo is a numbers game where players match randomly drawn numbers to the numbers on their cards. Each bingo card is a square grid with 25 spaces, and the columns of the grid are labeled with letters such as "B", "I", "N", "G", "O". The letters help to identify the number range in each column, for example, the "B" column may contain numbers 1 to 15.

One of the spaces in the middle of the grid is often a "free" space, and is marked as such. To play the game, each player is given a bingo card with numbers on it. A caller then draws numbers randomly and announces them, and players mark the corresponding numbers on their cards. The first player to match a pre-determined pattern of marked numbers, such as a straight line, all four corners, or a full card, calls out "Bingo!" to win the game. The game continues until one player wins, or multiple players win on the same round. [1]

---

## Challenge

Create a set of `n` bingo cards that are printed / outputted in sequence separated by one or two empty lines. The center field should be marked as `free`.

The output should be a 5x5 grid where columns are either separated by a single space, a tab or the grid should be fixed width, and the lines are separated by a single new line.

The randomness must be uniform, i.e. all possible permutations and combinations should be equally likely to occur. All numbers must be unique.

The numbers:

```
B = 1 - 15
I = 16 - 30
N = 31 - 45
G = 46 - 60
O = 61 - 75
```

The number `n` must be taken as input.

### Example output for `n = 3`:

```
B I N G O
1 16 31 46 61
2 17 32 47 62
3 18 free 48 63
4 19 34 49 64
5 20 35 50 65

B I N G O
6 30 40 53 64
5 20 35 50 70
4 25 free 51 69
7 22 32 52 68
11 23 38 49 67

B I N G O
10 25 40 55 70
11 26 41 56 71
12 27 free 57 73
13 28 43 58 73
14 29 44 59 74
```

Yes, those were definitely randomly created.

---

<sub>This challenge is based on the fact that I recently had to create 100 Bingo cards. It turned out that this part of the challenge was the easy one. Making it pretty, printable and presentable was the time consuming part.</sub>

[1] https://chat.openai.com/chat

Comment: [Not a duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2631/31516) of this similarly named challenge.

Comment: Can the "BINGO" be lowercase?

Comment: Doesn't this challenge duplicate https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/bingo-card-generator ?

Comment: @gildux, No. In my opinion it's not even close. Creating a list of 5 * 15 random numbers is a whole lot different than this one. The Python answer in this one is 193 bytes while a pyhton answer in the other one is 84 bytes. That alone should show the difference, in my opinion.

Comment: @Shaggy no, it should be uppercase.

Comment: I was thinking a more random bingo card could be generated by allowing each column access to the number space for neighbouring columns. e.g the first column could have 1-30 rather than 1-15 and column 3 could have 16-60 rather than 31-45. But obviously you still couldn't have duplicate numbers.
I think that would make the generation much harder as rather than shuffling 5 arrays and taking the first 5 of each you'd have overlapping number spaces and would have to be careful of picking dupes. [Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hedq62r/)
Is the idea worth a sandbox post?

Comment: By printed/outputted, that means that it must be displayed in stdout/error, not returned, correct?

Comment: A function can return it, as long a simple `print(output)` call prints it in the exact format described in the challenge. The print command can't specify the output format.

Comment: Sure, "creating a list of 5 \* 15 random numbers is a whole lot different than" doing it N given times… Why not?

Comment: @gildux I don't understand. Are you saying: "Sure, but it's still a duplicate", or "Sure, it's not a duplicate after all"?

Comment: In "my" language, MATLAB, golfing "create 5*15 random numbers" involves a completely different code than the code required to solve this challenge. Mixing numeric values with characters takes a bit of effort, and so does doing it several times without duplicating cards. I agree that in a language where replacing a numeric value with a character and adding a header to a numeric(?) array is trivial, then the differences aren't that big. In my, albeit biased, opnion, these are two different challenges that require _two different approaches_ in some languages, and is therefore not a duplicate.

Comment: By the way, I appreciate comments explaining why someone downvotes / VTC, so thanks for that... That's much better than votes with no explanations. :)

Comment: Yes, I was a bit ironic (saying sure for "if you want but it's still") …and when I read some answers that's exactly what they were doing (looping the previous golf, which of couse makes a slightly bigger and different code.)
But thanks for the explanation. Things become clearer when we adopt your view from MATLAB, and one should then finally agree they're not duplicate at all. Thanks for clarifying for me (and others.)

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `J`, 29 bytes

```
(‛₆ṫ⇧Ṅ75ɾ15ẇƛÞ℅5Ẏ;∩2≬2‛λċȦV⁋¶
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJKIiwiIiwiKOKAm+KChuG5q+KHp+G5hDc1yb4xNeG6h8abw57ihIU14bqOO+KIqTLiiawy4oCbzrvEi8imVuKBi8K2IiwiIiwiMyJd)

### Explained (old)

```
(        # input times:
75ɾ15ẇ   #   push the range [1, 75] split into chunks of 15 items
ƛÞ℅5Ẏ;   #   to each: random_permutation[:5]
∩        #   transpose
2≬2‛λċȦV #   tos[2][2] = "free"
‛₆ṫ⇧p    #   .prepend("BINGO")
vṄ⁋      #   .map(" ".join(x)).join("\n")
¶+,      #   + "\n" (then print)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic), 211 bytes

```
DIM b(5,5)
RANDOMIZE TIMER
INPUT n
FOR i=1TO n
ERASE b
?
?"B","I","N","G","O
FOR r=0TO 4
FOR c=0TO 4
4x=INT((c+RND)*15+1)
FOR p=0TO r
IF x=b(p,c)GOTO 4
NEXT p
IF(r=2)*(c=2)THEN?"free",ELSE?x,:b(r,c)=x
NEXT c,r,i
```

Try it at [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack)! Example run:

[image: An example run with input 3, showing 3 randomly generated bingo cards]

### Explanation/ungolfed

```
DIM b(5, 5)
RANDOMIZE TIMER
INPUT n
```

Declare `b` as a 5x5 array; we'll use this to track already-selected numbers and avoid duplicates. Seed the pseudo-random number generator using the current time. Prompt the user for the number of cards `n`.

```
FOR i = 1 TO n
```

Loop `n` times:

```
ERASE b
PRINT
PRINT "B", "I", "N", "G", "O"
```

Set all values in `b` to zero. Print a blank line followed by the B I N G O header. The commas in the `PRINT` statements separate the items by tabs, using a default tab stop of 14 columns.

```
FOR r = 0 TO 4
FOR c = 0 TO 4
```

Loop over rows 0 through 4; for each row, loop over columns 0 through 4.

```
4 x = INT((c + RND) * 15 + 1)
```

Label this as line number [4](https://xkcd.com/221), which we'll use as a `GOTO` target later. Set `x` to be a random integer, greater than or equal to `c*15+1`, and less than `(c+1)*15+1`.

```
FOR p = 0 TO r
IF x = b(p, c) THEN GOTO 4
NEXT p
```

Loop over each previous row `p`. If `x` equals the value in array `b` at row `p`, column `c`, go back to line 4 and generate a new random number.

```
IF (r = 2) * (c = 2) THEN
  PRINT "free",
ELSE
  PRINT x,
  b(r, c) = x
END IF
```

If both `r` and `c` are 2, print the string `"free"`; otherwise, print `x` and set the appropriate value in the `b` array to `x`. In both cases, end the print statement with a tab rather than a newline.

```
NEXT c, r, i
```

Close all the `FOR` loops.

---

Astute readers may have noticed this doesn't print a newline at the end of each row. Because of the size of the default tab stop, it just so happens that the sixth column wraps to the next line, so printing a newline explicitly is unnecessary (and, in fact, results in unwanted blank lines). This might be bending the I/O requirements a bit. If an explicit newline must be printed, modify the B I N G O line by adding `",` at the end, and add a line containing `?` in between the `FOR r` and `FOR c` headers.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 132 bytes

```javascript
f=N=>(F=n=>N?n<30?F[k=n%5]^(F[k]|=1<<(v=Math.random()*15))?(n++-17?"_BINGO"[n]||k*15-~v:'free')+` 
`[k>>2]+F(n):F(n):`
`+f(N-1):n)``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcnLCoJAFIDhvU8RQnhOg9IkEoij0MJo0fQAYo146aKdCRVX0qtP0ubng/9VTMVQ9s/P6JKuamMaIUUMqSARy4Qif5ukWStoHeRXWJTPgkcRTOJcjA@vL6jSb8ANDxATIMZcvk/s2@Ekjxc7o3ye2@W53yl0mr6uHWRqZamsjeNdzlIgDP9RlmINSJdjSKiUKTUNuqu9Tt@hAR/R/AA)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = N => (              // outer function taking the number N of grids
  F = n =>              // inner function taking a counter n
  N ?                   // if there's still a grid to process:
    n < 30 ?            //   if n is less than 30:
      F[k = n % 5]      //     k is the column index in [0..4]
      ^                 //     if F[k] is not equal to its updated value
      ( F[k] |= 1 << (  //     where the floor(v)-th bit is set
          v =           //     where v is
          Math.random() //     randomly picked in [0,15[
          * 15          //
      )) ?              //     then:
        ( n++ - 17 ?    //       if this is not the center cell:
            "_BINGO"[n] //         append either a BINGO letter (if n <= 5)
            ||          //         or
            k * 15 - ~v //         the number k * 15 + floor(v + 1)
          :             //       else:
            'free'      //         append the word 'free'
        ) +             //
        ` \n`[k >> 2] + //       append a line-feed if k = 4,
                        //       or a space otherwise
        F(n)            //       append the result of a recursive call to F
      :                 //     else:
        F(n)            //       try again
    :                   //   else:
      `\n` +            //     append a line-feed followed by
      f(N - 1)          //     the result of a recursive call to f
  :                     // else:
    n                   //   stop the recursion
)``                     // initial call to F with n zero'ish
```

Comment: Grids need only be separated by a single newline, so you can drop the one before the recursive call to `f`.

Comment: @Shaggy Not 100% sure about that. The challenge says _separated by one or two *empty* lines_.

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 123 bytes

```factor
[ [ "free"2 75 [1,b] 15 group [ 5 sample ] map flip
[ third set-nth ] keep "BINGO"1 group prefix simple-table. nl ] times ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY49D4JAEER7fsWEWkjQEBPtbIyNFsaKUBywBxeP4zyWRH/9uX60O/vejFYtTyHerqfzcYdR8ZAH5Xqa0Ydp8cb1mOmxkGvlJEk3jfCBmF8@GMcw0xfCnYIji32SbGKFCqkOROka2xJVsWpqFOXPKFmJWY3eEmphPbQ1PqnAgwmdlHHmxFeLkTzSg@y6pMWflWZtnpjNB89YNZZyOCvfbEYZWMdWWRvf)

- `[ ... ] times` Do something a number of times.

```
"free"                 ! "free"
2                      ! "free" 2
75                     ! "free" 2 75
[1,b]                  ! "free" 2 { 1 2 ... 75 }
15                     ! "free" 2 { 1 2 ... 75 } 15
group                  ! "free" 2 { { 1 2 .. 15 } { 16 17 .. 30 } ... { 61 62 .. 75 } }
[ 5 sample ] map       ! "free" 2 {
                       !     { 9 13 14 1 5 }
                       !     { 26 24 25 27 22 }
                       !     { 32 38 41 31 33 }
                       !     { 54 59 55 49 57 }
                       !     { 75 74 70 71 63 }
                       ! }
flip                   ! "free" 2 {
                       !     { 9 26 32 54 75 }
                       !     { 13 24 38 59 74 }
                       !     { 14 25 41 55 70 }
                       !     { 1 27 31 49 71 }
                       !     { 5 22 33 57 63 }
                       ! }
[ third set-nth ] keep ! {
                       !     { 9 26 32 54 75 }
                       !     { 13 24 38 59 74 }
                       !     { 14 25 "free" 55 70 }
                       !     { 1 27 31 49 71 }
                       !     { 5 22 33 57 63 }
                       ! }
"BINGO"                ! { ... } "BINGO"
1 group                ! { ... } { "B" "I" "N" "G" "O" }
prefix                 ! {
                       !     { "B" "I" "N" "G" "O" }
                       !     { 9 26 32 54 75 }
                       !     { 13 24 38 59 74 }
                       !     { 14 25 "free" 55 70 }
                       !     { 1 27 31 49 71 }
                       !     { 5 22 33 57 63 }
                       ! }
simple-table.          ! output to stdout
nl                     ! newline
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mR`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>39</s> 38 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
75õ òF Ëö¤v5Ãg2Èh2`fe`ÃÕi"BINGO"¬ m¸·
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW1S&code=NzX1IPJGIMv2pHY1w2cyyGgyYGacZWDD1WkiQklOR08irCBtuLc&footer=aVI&input=MwoteA)

```
75õ òF Ëö¤v5Ãg2Èh2`fe`ÃÕi"BINGO"¬ m¸·     :Implicit map of range [0,input)
75õ                                        :Range [1,75]
    ò                                      :Partitions of length
     F                                     :  15
       Ë                                   :Map
        ö¤                                 :  Shuffle
          v5                               :  First 5 elements
            Ã                              :End map
             g2                            :Modify the element at 0-based index 2 by
               È                           :Passing it through the following function
                h2                         :  Replace the element at 0-based index 2 with
                  `fe`                     :  Compressed string "free"
                      Ã                    :End modification
                        Õ                  :Transpose
                         i                 :Prepend
                          "BINGO"¬         :  "BINGO", split into an array
                                   m       :Map
                                    ¸      :  Join with spaces
                                     ·     :Join with newlines
                                           :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Comment: Came up with this independently but it's pretty close to yours: [37](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW1S&code=NccqRsQp80Yg9jXDZzJfaDJgZpxlYMPVaSJCSU5HTyKsIG24tw&footer=aVI&input=MQ)

Comment: [37 with explanation](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW1S&code=NccqRsQp80Yg9jXDZzJfaDJgZpxlYMPVaSJCSU5HTyKsIG24tw&footer=aVI&input=MQ)

Comment: Oops golfed yours to [36](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW1S&code=NzX1IPJGIMv2NcNnMl9oMmBmnGVgw9VpIkJJTkdPIqwgbbi3&footer=aVI&input=Mw)

Comment: That won't work, @Jacob; `A.ö(n)` allows for duplicates to be included, hence why I'm shuffling and then grabbing the first 5 items.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>54</s> <s>52</s> 49 bytes

```
ＦＮ«≔⪪BINGO¹θＦ²⁵⊞θ⎇⁼κ¹²free‽⁻⁺×¹⁵﹪κ⁵…¹¦¹⁶θ⟦Ｅ⪪θ⁵⪫κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BisIwEEDP9iuGnGYge2iX7sWTwiIV1OL6A1FTDaZJmzQLIn57Ng07hzm9N28ud@EuVugYO@sAGzOEaR/6s3RIBK9isfJe3Qz@DFpNyNbNfnNgHEriMNKyWGSrqgna4O84cjhJZ4R74vcYhPb4SGyVYNY5KZN4FOZqe9wpEzy2Oq2T6qXHsuaws9eg7azURBm9SSzTgS/KuTSpmEMh0WL4/2qcBQ5bq8wsM2CZfBetU2bCQMsYP@PHr/4D) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Now inspired by @Arnauld's answer.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Input `n` and loop that many times.

```
≔⪪BINGO¹θ
```

Start with a list of `BINGO` as separate characters which will make up the first row.

```
Ｆ²⁵
```

Loop `25` times.

```
⊞θ⎇⁼κ¹²free‽⁻⁺×¹⁵﹪κ⁵…¹¦¹⁶θ
```

Put the word `free` in the middle cell, otherwise take a random element of the appropriate numeric range for the cell but subtracting all of the numbers generated so far, and push the result to the list.

```
⟦Ｅ⪪θ⁵⪫κ
```

Split into rows of five cells, join the rows on spaces and output the resulting board double-spaced from the next board.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 39 bytes

```
VQkjd"BINGO"jjL\ Cc5X%3s.SMc5S75y6"free
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PywwOytFycnTz91fKSvLJ0bBOdk0QtW4WC/YN9k02Ny00kwprSg19f9/UwA)

#### Explanation

```
                                           # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
VQ                                         # for N in range(Q):
  k                                        # print a newline
   jd"BINGO"                               # print BINGO joined on spaces
                             S75           # range(1,76)
                           c5              # split into 5 equal parts
                        .SM                # randomly shuffle each part
                       s                   # join the parts back together
                     %3                    # take every third element
                    X           y6"free    # replace the 12th element with "free"
                  c5                       # split into 5 equal parts again
                 C                         # transpose
             jL\                           # join each part on whitespace, converting all elements to strings
            j                              # join on newlines and print
```

Comment: @Arnauld See, I knew that was part of the challenge and then forgot to do it before posting. Fixed now for a measly 3 bytes. Thanks for keeping me honest :)

Comment: OP's note: I'll allow the single leading newline. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 32 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
F75L5äε.r5£N<i'€²2ǝ}}ø‘Èß‘Sš»,¶?
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9vc2FiaWX//0Y3NUw1w6TOtS5yNcKjTjxpJ@KCrMKyMsedfX3DuOKAmMOIw5/igJhTxaHCuyzCtj///zM)

**Explanation:**

```python
F                # Loop the (implicit) input-integer amount of times:
 75L             #  Push a list in the range [1,75]
    5ä           #  Split it into five equal-sized parts
      ε          #  Map over each part:
       .r        #   Randomly shuffle the list
         5£      #   Then only keep the first 5 integers
       N<i       #   If the index is 2:
          '€²   '#    Push dictionary string "free"
             2ǝ  #    Insert it at (0-based) index 2 into the quintuplet-list
      }}         #  Close both the if-statement and map
        ø        #  Zip/transpose the matrix; swapping rows/columns
         ‘Èß‘    #  Push dictionary string "BINGO"
             S   #  Convert it to a list of characters: ["B","I","N","G","O"]
              š  #  Prepend it to the matrix
               » #  Join each inner list by spaces; and then each string by newlines
 ,               #  Pop and print it with trailing newline
  ¶?             #  And print an additional newline character
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `'€²` is `"free"` and `‘Èß‘` is `"BINGO"`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```lisp
La{Y ZSH*\,75CH5y@2@2:"free"P_JsPBnMyH5PE"BINGO"}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhY3DX0SqyMVooI9tGJ0zE2dPUwrHYwcjKyU0opSU5UC4r2KA5zyfCs9TANclZw8_dz9lWohGqH6F0cbx0KZAA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
La{...}
```

Given command-line argument `a`, loop that many times:

```lisp
Y ZSH*\,75CH5
      \,75            ; Inclusive range from 1 to 75
          CH5         ; Chop into 5 equal sections
   SH*                ; Randomly shuffle each section
  Z                   ; Transpose
Y                     ; Yank that result into the y variable

y@2@2:"free"          ; Set the element of y at index 2,2 to the string "free"

P_JsPBnMyH5PE"BINGO"
        yH5           ; Take the first 5 elements of y
           PE"BINGO"  ; Prepend the element "BINGO"
       M              ; Map to each:
 _Js                  ;  Join on spaces
    PBn               ;  and push a newline to the end of the resulting string
P                     ; Print that list, concatenated, with a trailing newline
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utils, 120

```bash
for((;j++<$1;));{
for((;++i<75;));{
a+=" <(shuf -i$i-$[i+=14] -n5)"
}
eval paste$a|sed '1iB	I	N	G	O
3s/\w*/free/3
$a
'
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SEPDOktb20bF0FpT07qaCyKirZ1pY24KEUnUtlVSsNEozihNU9DNVMnUVYnO1LY1NIlV0M0z1VTiquVKLUvMUShILC5JVUmsKU5NUVA3zHTi9OT043Tn9OcyLtaPKdfSTytKTdU35lJJ5FLnqv3//78xAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 46 bytes

Full program. Prompts for `n`.

```apl
('BINGO'{'free'}¨@3@4⍤⍪(15×…4)+⍤1⍉)⍤2↑5?¨⎕5⍴15
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94L@GupOnn7u/erV6WlFqqnrtoRUOxg4mj3qXPOpdpWFoenj6o4ZlJpraQAHDR72dmkDa6FHbRFP7Qyse9U01fdS7xdAUZNB/BTAo4DIGAA)

`⎕5⍴15` prompt for `n` and join that 5, then use that as dimensions for an array of 15s

`5?¨` for each 15, get 5 random numbers in the range 1 through that, without replacement

`↑` mix this matrix of lists into an `n`-by-5-by-5 array with each row being a randome 5-of-15

`(`…`)⍤2` on each layer:

`⍉`  transpose, so the 5-of-15 rows become columns

`(`…`)+⍤1` add the following to each row:

`…4` the numbers 0 through 4

`15×` fifteen multiplied by those

`'BINGO'`…`⍤⍪` prepend a row of the given letters, then:

…`@4` at row 4:

…`@3` at column 3:

`{`…`}¨` replace each value (though there's only one) with:

`'free'` the given word

Comment: @Shaggy Lack of sleep, I guess. Should be alright now.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>262</s> 225 bytes

- -37 thanks to c--

```c
a[6][5]={L"BINGO"};f(n,i,j,k,r){--n&&puts("",f(n));for(j=5;j--;)for(k=i=0;k||++i<6;k||(a[i][j]=r))for(r=j*15+rand(k=i)%15+1;--k&&a[k][j]-r;);for(i=0;i<6;i+=puts(""))for(j=0;j<5;)printf(i*j-9?i?"%d	":"%c	":"free	",a[i][j++]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU/BisIwED3rV5RAS2ISUJYKGoOwl2VBdj8g5BDaRibBKLHupfbba2L3MjPvzeO9mYafm2aajNpqVWs5nNDn98/XLxqFxYEBc8yzSAbOQ1XdHv0dI8TShhBhrxE7WQvHuSAZeAlyLfzzSSkctnnARoFWTstI3ooo3WpT02hCm9WkTGAjOPdVZZTPSh7F7JytsgtQ@R87W7jEu0MtyC1C6C2GleO7IxxR2S7QHpVNrjZ23QKxOZ1STcQ4JXVxMRDw3xVaUgzLori/D@nh0uF1eigxFn@kPk4v)

Ungolfed (`` ` `` used instead of literal tab character):

```c
a[6][5]={L"BINGO"}; // bingo array, with header
f(n, // number of cards to generate
  i,j, // row and column
  k, // random number row checker
  r // random number
 ) {
  --n && puts("",f(n)); // recursively print cards, adding newline
  for(j=5;j--;) // for each column
      for(k=i=0;k||++i<6;k||(a[i][j]=r)) // for each row (redo duplicates)
        for(r=j*15+rand(k=i)%15+1;--k&&a[k][j]-r;); // detect duplicates
    for(i=0;i<6;i+=puts("")) // mark middle item as free; print board
      for(j=0;j<5;)
        printf(i*j-9?i?"%d`":"%c`":"free`",a[i][j++]);
}
```

Comment: it looks like you don't need to clear the array at all, because you only check for duplicates in the elements you just set

Comment: [225 bytes](https://tio.run/##LU/BisIwED3rV5RAS2ISUJYKGoOwl2VBdj8g5BDaRibBKLHupfbba2L3MjPvzeO9mYafm2aajNpqVWs5nNDn98/XLxqFxYEBc8yzSAbOQ1XdHv0dI8TShhBhrxE7WQvHuSAZeAlyLfzzSSkctnnARoFWTstI3ooo3WpT02hCm9WkTGAjOPdVZZTPSh7F7JytsgtQ@R87W7jEu0MtyC1C6C2GleO7IxxR2S7QHpVNrjZ23QKxOZ1STcQ4JXVxMRDw3xVaUgzLori/D@nh0uF1eigxFn@kPk4v)

Comment: [221 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY/NasMwDMfP3VMEQ4Jd29AyUthUU9hlDMb2AMYHk8RFNnWLm@2S5tkzu91Fnz/9JXXy2HXLYvXO6Nao6ZO8fXy9f5MZHI0ChRdBJDZJGZvm8jNeKSEidxgDd07Uqxa8lMBKEhSqDYTbjXPc70pArUajvVGJ3Ymk/Hrb8mRjX2hW52QLUoamsToUUiZ4KAPnPov8r3yMF3nct8AuCePoKK69fDn4A6n7FXkldVesS8OwIsJmMY2cGwbzkunqZDHS3zP2rJqequp6P2LE00A3@ZlccfQ5@3n5Aw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>38</s> 36 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
75s15Ẋ€ḣ€5Z“ƝM»€3¦€3¦“BINGO”ṭṚK€Y⁷Ṅ)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/ctNjQ9OGurkdNax7uWAwkTaMeNcw5Ntf30G4gx/jQMijZMMfJ08/d/1HD3Ic71z7cOcsbKB75qHH7w50tmv///zcGAA)

Most of the credit goes to *@cairdcoinheringaahing* and *@UnrelatedString* for helping me [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57815/jelly-hypertraining).

- -2 thanks to UnrelatedString

This can probably be a bit shorter, though.

##### Explanation

```python
75        # 75 (implicit range)
  s15     # Split into 15 parts
     Ẋ€   # Random permutation of each
ḣ€5       # First 5 elements of each
   Z      # Transpose
    “ƝM»  # Replace ↓ with "free"
€3¦€3¦    # The third item in the third item (1-indexed)
“BINGO”   # Push "BINGO"
       ṭṚ # Append and reverse (i.e. prepend)
K€        # Join each by spaces
  Y⁷      # Join by newlines and append a newline
    Ṅ     # Print
     )    # Repeat input number of times
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 151 bytes

```
from random import *
print("B I N G O")
x=lambda n:n*15+randint(0,15)
[print(*[*("free"if(i==2 and j==2)else x(j)for j in range(5))])for i in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>198 166</s> 157 bytes

```python
lambda n:exec('m=["BINGO",*map(list,zip(*[sample(range(i,i+15),5)for i in range(1,75,15)])),""];m[3][2]="free";[print(*i)for i in m];'*n)
from random import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYyxDsIgFAB3v4KwFJClNo2JpIuLcdEPQAa0oC/pA0IZ1J/HGgenGy536VUeMXTVD5c6WbyOloSde7oba3DQdH88Hc5UCrSJTTAX@YbEhJ4tpsmxbMPdMZCwbnsue@5jJkAgkJ9o5baXizGcS0qNQt0ZvTED9dk5qnTKEAoT8O/QqEYEvvI54ncyLgBMMRdRPet4/QA)

(ATO isn't working right now so I switched to TIO)

- -32 thanks to tsh

This can probably be golfed a bit more.

Comment: typo at line 2, need space before `or`

Comment: @IuriGuilherme it's not a typo - Python will let you remove the space after a number in most cases.

Comment: not in python3.11 anymore

Comment: So change to say it's Python prior 3.11 or add the space…

Comment: 166 bytes: `lambda n:exec('m=["BINGO",*map(list,zip(*[sample(range(i,i+15),5)for i in range(1,75,15)])),""];m[3][2]="FREE";[print(*i,sep="\t")for i in m];'*n)`

Comment: @tsh thanks. I don't think the `sep="\t"` is necessary, so I removed that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 94 bytes

```
{join "

",({S:13th/\d+/free/}((<B I N G O>,|[Z] (1..75).rotor(15)».pick(5)).join("
"))xx$_)}
```

- `(1..75).rotor(15)` splits the range 1-75 into five subranges of size 15: 1-15, 16-30, etc.
- `».pick(5)` selects five distinct random elements from each of those subranges.
- `[Z]` reduces that list of lists of random choices with the `Z`ip operator.  It effectively transposes the matrix, so the 1-15 selections are in the first column instead of the first row.
- `<B I N G O>,|...` prepends the header row to the lists of numbers.
- `.join("\n")` joins the rows with newlines, producing a Bingo board as a single string.  The actual code uses a single newline character between the quotes to save a byte.
- `S:13th/\d+/free/` changes the thirteenth occurrence of a number in that string to `free`.
- `xx $_` replicates the preceding process a number of times given by the input argument `$_`, producing a list of board strings.
- `join "\n\n"` joins those boards together with two newlines between them.